# How can I reference foreign objects with  ormLite annotations on android

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to use ORM annotations to apply my object relationship but I can't seem to find a way to do this properly using ormLite annotations, because I cant use jpa them on android, I think, but has someone done this, if not can someone tell me how to import jpa on android to use with orm?

```
@DataBaseTable(tableName="some_object")
public Class SomeObject{

    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign= true,foreignAutoCreate=true, foreignAutoRefresh=true)
    private List<ReferencedObject> referencedObjects;
}

@DataBaseTable(tableName="referenced_object")
public Class ReferencedObject{

    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Uh, what's the question?

Comment: How to correctly create object relationships using  ormLite annotations, on a  oneToOne or ManytoMany basis or OneToMany just how its done with JPA

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to show this information.  As the question currently sits, it should be removed.

Comment: ok @Gray I will edit my question but do you have any ideeas about it?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a ForeignCollection instead of your `List` http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/ForeignCollection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `ForeignCollection` instead of your `List`

- [Documentation on foreign collections](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection)
- [JavaDocs for ForeignCollection](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/ForeignCollection.html)

Here's the code:

```
@DataBaseTable(tableName="some_object")
public Class SomeObject{

    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private Long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection< ReferencedObject> referencedObjects;
}

///////////////////////////

@DataBaseTable(tableName="referenced_object")
public Class ReferencedObject{

    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private Long id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    private SomeObject obj;
}
```

Comment: @Gray Given that you have a reference in `ReferencedObject` back to `SomeObject` to maintain the foreign key relationship. When creating the `ReferencedObject` do you have to call a setter on the `SomeObject ` to initialize it with the `SomeObject` data?

Comment: Yes @HoraceHeaven.  The `obj` field needs to be set when the `ReferencedObject` is created to make the connection.